# When joining two tables, add blank space for non existing data, do not remove the whole row (left outer join)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I have the following issue:

Table1 looks like this:

| User |
| --- |
| Ana |
| Mary |
| Lory |
| Jake |

Table2 looks like this:

| User | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| Mary | Apples |
| Lory | Oranges |

I should now make a visual where every user from Table1 is shown, doesn't matter if he has input in Table2 or not. However, there should be a column Fruit, too, and if the user has nothing in Fruit column (he is not in Table2), there should be blank space.

So this is the right solution:

| User | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| Ana |  |
| Mary | Apples |
| Lory | Oranges |
| Jake |  |

When I try to unite those two tables, users from Table1 that don't have fruit value disappear. I tried to add a new column in Table1 that says data/no data and then tried to filter like that, but it just didn't work. The moment I add Fruit table, data logically disappears. It is impossible for me to join tables or to add Fruit column in Table1 because the real data is way bigger and more serious than this example.

It would be ideal if there would be some measure, for example: if there is no data, add blank space. I tried something like that, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Well not really. I can't create a relationship like that because of the other visuals and the way my data works (Table1 is the main, with the key). Relationship now is one to many (single direction) from Table1 to Table2 and I can not really change it. I could maybe change from single to both. But I did get a good hint. I am now trying to solve how to create a left outer join without changing the relationship.

Comment: Is there a possibility to add one column to the other table, but that that one column is connected with left outer join? In other words, Table 1 has more than one column. Can we choose only one column (Users) and add that column to Table 2 but so that the whole column is added? I tried with Column = RELATED(Table2[User]) and the column is added, however the once that don't match are filtered out.

Comment: I kind of succeeded. I went to power query, merged queries (right outer) then chose only users to be shown. It could probably be more sophisticated and take less memory, but yea.

Comment: @Ravena: Please (consider posting the answer, and then) close this question. It shows up as an open question with 0 answers.

Comment: @JSmart523 Ah ok, I’m new here so I’m not really introduced to stuff like that. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me: I went to power query, merged queries (right outer) then chose only users to be shown. It could probably be more sophisticated and with less memory being used, but this did it for me.